# I want to remotely run linux programs and return output using C# or similar language

Tags: c#, android, linux, arm

I am planning for my Capstone for my degree.

In this project I will be utilizing an ARM board loaded with a specific linux distribution. (Currently either Debian or Ubuntu based.)

This ARM board will be sitting on a network using either WiFi or wired LAN or combinations of both or multiple WiFi connections.

I will be using a PC likely running Windows to access this ARM board. Due to the nature of the intention of this setup I will NOT be using the LAN connection to control the ARM board but will be using a USB connection from the PC to the board.

I have seen some applications on an Android tablet where they install a Ubuntu host and run it on the android box in the background. They can then access this via VNC, telnet or ssh. They then have built native applications for the Android that communicate with the Ubuntu host and remotely run software on the Ubuntu host and use the data returned. Basically they are building a GUI that remotely runs the commands and displays the results in some form.

I want to build a system for my capstone that uses 1 or more ARM boards to do menial work while the PC listens to them and returns status as it becomes available.

I have seen mention of using socket programming and the Expect package written in tcl. Are these the best technologies I can use or is there something better for me to look at? Currently I am doing a bunch of work in both C# and Java but the end result program I will be building is likely to be in C# so I am looking for information to head me in the right direction. I am 3-5 years away from my degree so I am not against making a new library in C or C# to do the work for me. So porting Expect COULD be an option. I ultimately need something that works very quickly due to the nature of my intended application and I need isolation of the PC from the LAN so I will NOT be using the LAN for the control connection.

Thanks for any help or guidance!

Rodney

Comment: I know you can run Python on Raspberry Pi; I'm not aware of a .NET port.  Python would be a fine choice for socket programming.

Comment: +1 for python. something like twisted matrix may be helpful since it is event based. C socket programming could be another option, but you would have to poll.

Comment: I suggest you to install Linux on your laptop to become much more familiar with it. Also compiling on Linux/x86-64 for a Linux/ARM is probably easier than compiling on Windows for a Linux/ARM

Comment: Since this original posting I have picked up a raspberry pi 2/b+ to play with. I want to connect to the RP from my laptop and run CLI programs on the RP controlled from the laptop and return the results back to the laptop.  Debating the best course to do this so I this is the question as it stands now. I want a reliable connection between laptop and RP. One that can't be killed off without major effort. Any software written will likely be done in C/C++ on the RP and probably C# on the laptop for performance and security reasons.